# Javascript canvas arc is not drawing according to angle

Tags: javascript

Hi I am having a problem with drawing a graph. The situation is there are number of days remaining and I need to draw and arc

```
var eAngle          = tax * 0.0172;

var c               = document.getElementById("tax");
var ctx             = c.getContext("2d");

ctx.beginPath();

ctx.arc(100,100,70,1.5 , Math.PI * eAngle, true);

ctx.stroke();
```

Also how can I write some text in the middle of that arc circle.

Comment: what is going wrong? When you say arc is not drawn according to the angle?

Comment: I dont think that the problem has anything to do with php @Epodax. I'd request OP to remove that tag.

Comment: i calculated the how many radians/day    2 X 365/3.14  which is 0.0172. So if I say draw a graph showing number of days passed but it is drawing not according to angle. i tried to put 365 days  and it was only drawing 70% of circle

Comment: Please remove php tag it was typing mistake

Comment: @MuhammadWaqas: Do I understand you correctly that you want one year to draw a full circle?

Comment: @Drenmi yes you are right

Comment: When do eAngle = 2*M_PI/365 and then your angle will be day*eAngle.

Comment: @mlkn i am doing the same but the arc is not drawing accordingly

Comment: Could you perhaps add an image that shows what you want the final result to look like? I am having trouble understanding what is 'wrong' with the solution provided by @drenmi below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have adjusted the code a little bit. First of, we need to know the angle every *day* in your year gets. I'm going to say that would be a full circle (`Math.PI * 2`) divided by 365 (or 366 when its one-of-*those*-years). Then it is a matter of correctly understanding the arc function:

```
arc(x, y, radius, angle (0 = x-axis to the right), end angle (starting x-axis where 1 radian is a full circle), counterclockwise (true is counterclockwise drawing from start until the end angle, and false or ommitting is the regular clockwise angle);
```

In the end, this will work:

```
context.arc(100, 100, 50, -Math.PI / 2, -Math.PI / 2 + day * (Math.PI * 2 / 365), false);
```

Where, in order, the arguments are: x-position, y-position, radius, -90 degrees (to start from the y-axis instead of the x), whatever this outputs when you input a day plus the offset of the previous argument.

To draw text on top of this., you can simply use the canvas `fillText` function.

```js
var dayArc = Math.PI * 2 / 365;
var dayN   = 0;
var offset = -Math.PI / 2;

var canvas = document.getElementById("tax")
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

setInterval(function(){
  dayN = dayN > 364 ? 0 : dayN+1;
  canvas.width = 500;
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(100, 100, 50, offset, offset  + dayN * dayArc, false);
  context.stroke();

  context.textAlign = 'center';
  context.font = "24px 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif";
  context.fillText((365-dayN) + '/365', 100, 110);
}, 1000 / 60);
```

```html
<canvas id="tax" widht="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you @somethinghere . The problem was i was starting the angle from 90 and i should subtract that from ending angle. now it works fine for me. The next thing i am looking for writing number of days in the middle of circle. Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: Text printing with canvas is in my snippet, I have added how to show the remaining days right now, but this isn't a hard part. Make sure to have a read through MDNs very comprehensive documentation on Canvas - its really a good read.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. So I would split up the calculations, to make it clearer what's going on. We know that a full circle is `Math.PI * 2` radians. So we keep that separate.

Since we only want a fraction of a circle, representing the number of days out of a year, we keep a separate variable, say, `fractionOfCircle`, and then multiply them for our final result.

```
var fractionOfCircle = days / 365;

var canvas = document.getElementById("tax");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.beginPath();

ctx.arc(100, 100, 70, 1.5, Math.PI * 2 * fractionOfCircle, true);

ctx.stroke();
```

To put a text within the circle, my first approach would be to overlay an HTML element, like a `div`, and position the text accordingly.

Comment: i am doing the same thing. It is drawing the arc in totally wrong way.

Comment: Could you provide an image of what you want it to look like? The only thing I can see wrong with this is that the starting point of the circle is 1.5, which is better off being 0 - but that only changes the starting angle.